# Handling clicks on label for custom input component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with a custom input component, which is supposed to work as a replacement for an `<input>`. Everything works fine except how clicks on a `<label>` that is targeting my component works. Reading the [docs on `label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), I expect to get a `click` event on my component when the label is clicked, but I don't get anything.

I.e. my HTML looks like this:

```html
<label for="mycomponent">Some label</label>
<my-component id="mycomponent"></my-component>
```

with `my-component` being a component that implements a `@HostListener` for `click`. The problem I have now is that the `click` handler is never triggered by clicking the *label*, it works of course if I click directly on the component. How can I react to the label being clicked inside the component so that I can manually forward this to the `input` inside my component?

I've created a sample project here: https://github.com/Anteru/ng-component-focus-test

The behavior I want is that both labels work the same, i.e. clicking on the label focuses the input. For the user, it shouldn't make a difference if they use a "plain old" input or my fancy component.

Comment: Please show us the code of `my-component`. You need to create an Input that will take an ID which will be the input ID then set that ID to the underlying input tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there're a better aproach, but you always can use ViewChild in your `my-component`

```
 @ViewChild('myinput',{static:true,read:ElementRef}) myInput
```

And use

```
<label (click)="myComponent.myInput.nativeElement.focus()">Hello</label>
<my-component #myComponent ></my-component>
```

Comment: The problem here is that the client of my component doesn't know what the input element within my component is, so this is much more complicated than I would like. I guess I could ask the label `click` event to be forwarded to `my-component`'s `click` manually, but that's still not as nice as a plain old input.

Comment: You always can create a function in your component (e.g. called "focus") and call in click: `(click)="myComponent.focus()"` or add a new `@Input` label and make that the label belongs to the component. Sorry I can not imagine another approach :(